# Anacondaにおける仮想環境の維持及び保存

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Windows10でAnacondaを用い、Anaconda Navigatorで仮想環境を作成、スタートメニューからSpyder(hoge)を起動させ仮想環境上で作業させています。
その際、パッケージの追加はAnacondaが壊れないよう可能ならばNavigator上からGUIでcondaでインストール、だめならばNavigatorからTerminalを開きpipでインストールしています。

この際、一度SpyderとNavigatorを落とすとインストールしたパッケージが消えてしまいました。
保存等の操作をする必要はあるのでしょうか。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 仮想環境が異なればパッケージも異なるので，違う環境にアクセスしてるとかではありませんでしょうか？デフォルトの仮想環境は(base)なので，別の仮想環境でパッケージをインストールしたのであれば，そちらにアクセスする必要があるかと思います．

Comment: パッケージを入れた仮想環境をクローン、クローン先を開いてもパッケージははいっていないようだったのでクローン元に戻っても入っていない、という感じだったので勘違いかもしれません。失礼いたしました。